# How to use paginate with sortBy in laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

What I'm trying to do is: First, sort the result of the collection using `sortBy` method in laravel, like so:

```
$users = User::with('user_profile', 'posts')
           ->whereHas('roles', function($query){
                 return $query->where('slug', 'moderator');
           })->get()
           ->sortBy(function($user){
                 return $user->user_profile->country . " - " . $user->posts->name;
           });
```

Now, when I use `paginate(10)` after the `sortBy` method, it returns an error. I also tried to use `orderBy` method to make it work, but I cannot use my callback function to order them according to the desired output. How can I use `paginate` in sortBy? Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

`User.php`

```
public function user_profile(){
    return $this->hasOne('Modules\Pages\Models\UserProfile');
}


public function posts(){
    return $this->hasOne('Modules\Pages\Models\Post');
}
```

Comment: Please post the `user_profile` and `posts` relationships.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Please see the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `orderBy()` and JOINs:

```php
$users = User::select('users.*')
    ->join('user_profiles', 'user_profiles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('posts', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->whereHas('roles', function($query){
        $query->where('slug', 'moderator');
    })
    ->orderByRaw("concat(user_profiles.country, ' - ', posts.name)")
    ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: Is it safe to use these queries?

Comment: Do you mean regarding SQL injections? Yes, there is no user input.

Comment: I got an error. Maybe some of my users don't have posts yet?

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'users.id `` inner join`

Comment: Is that the whole message? What's your Laravel version?

Comment: `Laravel v5.1.`

Comment: Just added `=`?

Comment: That should fix the problem.